# rails tutorial literred with hard coded error messages, how to localize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization

Just going through the rails tutorial, and I noticed that the error messages are all hard coded in the controller actions etc.

What is the pattern to pull these from a localized resource file? (I'm on chapter 9 so far)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your en.yml file or create a new file in config/locales/messages.en.yml  add your hard-coded error messages from the controller

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      not_found: "The record you searched doesn't exist"
      update_failed: "Your updated operation failed"
```

To display this messages use

```
(t "errors.messages.not_found")
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a [whole another guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) about that.

(don't know what tutorial you're using, but from my experience guides.rubyonrails.org provides the best Rails reference material on the web)

Comment: @Blankman Never heard of it, but good luck! And you can always consult official rails guide if you have any difficulties.